# How to validate the verification code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am creating a form with verification code.
The verification code is an image, right?(Let me know, if i am wrong.)
How to know that the user is entering correct verification code. (That means how to validate the verification code in javascript, even need to check user is entering the correct case.) or may be in servlet is also fine.
Here, is my code in html page.

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function ValidateForm(frm) {
if (frm.CaptchaCode.value == "") {alert('Enter web form code.');frm.CaptchaCode.focus();return false;}  
return false;
}
function ReloadCaptchaImage(captchaImageId) {
var obj = document.getElementById(captchaImageId);
var src = obj.src;
var date = new Date();
var pos = src.indexOf('&rad=');
if (pos >= 0) { src = src.substr(0, pos); }
obj.src = src + '&rad=' + date.getTime();
return false; }
</script>
<i>Enter web form code*:</i>
<input id="CaptchaCode" name="CaptchaCode" type="text" style="width:80px; border:1px solid #999999;" maxlength="6" />
<a href="http://www.SnapHost.com"><img id="CaptchaImage" alt="Web Form Code" title="Anti-spam web forms"
style="margin-left:20px; border:1px solid #999999"
src="http://www.SnapHost.com/captcha/WebForm.aspx?id=HQWK4M77B9KH&ImgType=2" /></a>
<br /><a href="#" onclick="return ReloadCaptchaImage('CaptchaImage');">
<span style="font-size:12px;">reload image</span></a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The actual implementation deppends rather on the server (PHP) code, than the client side implementation

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't. It must not be available on client side. Otherwise, robot could run the javascript as well - and your work would be pointless.

However, you can do two things:

### AJAX request

You can send the code user entered to the server and the server will validate the answer and send back "yes" or "no".
**Pros:**

- easy
- you can regenerate code after every attempt

**Cons:**

- costs a little bandwidth
- upon lag, it may take a while before AJAX call loads

### Asymethric enctription

This is a bit more vulnerable, yet much more elegant method. Generally, what you do is that you send a hash (such as `md5`, but I'd recommend stronger algorithm) with the captcha code. As you know, hashed data cannot be retrieved back. So in the javascript code, you need to hash the code user has entered and compare it to hash you've send with the page.

**Pros:**

- the user is instantly informed about the state
- no bandwidth problems

**Cons:**

- you must implement the hash function on the client side
- there are unlimited number of attempts to validate the same code - this means breaking your captcha will be as hard as breaking the actual hash algorythm (nothing to worry about at all)

Comment: :-)   Oh.. ok, i am a new learner. I know html, javascript and servlets. SO, i just want to know is there any way to do it in javascript. I don't know both AJAX and asymmetric encription. That's ok. Thank You very much.

Comment: And do you know how captcha works? If you do you must also know, that without server's cooperation, you have no chance to guess the result.

Comment: Oh and please, do not call yourself a *learner* if you're not willing to *learn*.